# How to align each string in text in field column of ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportingservices-2005, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-grouping

I have a field like this in the column field in ssrs.

QUINIDINEssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss GL INJ 80MG/ML
FLECAINIDEssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss TAB 50MG
TAMBOCORsssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss TAB 50MG

and how can i align  align like this...

QUINIDINEssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss GL INJ 80MG/ML
FLECAINIDEssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss(emptyspaceeeeeeeee)TAB 50MG
TAMBOCORsssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss(emptyspa)TAB 50MG

each part of string align properly...

Any help...

Comment: I presume those "s" are spaces? Do you need to preserve the spaces between "TAB" and "50MG"?

Comment: hi eric,FOR FIRST ROW : 1st string = QUINIDINEssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss 2nd=GL 3rd=INJ 4th80MG/ML SECOND ROW :   1st string : FLECAINIDEssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss 2nd:TAB 3rd:50MG so..all 1st ,2nd and 3rd string align propoerly for all rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there are two ways to do this that I worked out, and neither is particularly elegant so I'd be surprised if someone doesn't have a better solution.

"t.a" in the code below is your table and column.

The SQL way:

```
SUBSTRING(t.a,1,CHARINDEX('  ',t.a,1))+REPLICATE('_',20)+REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(t.a),1,CHARINDEX('  ',REVERSE(t.a),1)))
```

Change the value being replicated above from '*' to ' ' and you are in business.  I left it as '*' to illustrate what it's doing.

The SSRS way, which is better from a DB standpoint:

```
=Mid(Fields!a.Value,1,InStr(Fields!a.Value,"  "))+StrDup(20,"_")+StrReverse(Mid(StrReverse(Fields!a.Value),1,InStr(StrReverse(Fields!a.Value),"  ")))
```

This is precisely the same formula, executed by SSRS instead of by SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

I once used `Switch` to append spaces to a column field, like in the following example:

```
=Switch(LEN(Fields!FamilyMemberName.Value) = 1, " ",
LEN(Fields!FamilyMemberName.Value) = 2, "  ",
LEN(Fields!FamilyMemberName.Value) = 3, "   ")
```

But I didn't have to bother about the expression getting longer, since I know exactly how many spaces I should append and it wasn't more than 15.

You could use `Switch` in your case too or you could write a VB function in the `Code` tab of `Report Properties` window and pass the values, use some loops to generate the spaces you require.

Or it's much easier in MS SQL, all you got to do is append `SPACE(NoOfSpacesInInteger)` to the field.